# Forensic Linguistics; 'Stupid people' or 'Stupid woman' - Do we know what Jeremy Corbyn said?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

In the UK, some of the debates in the Houses of Parliament are televised. On 18th December 2018, Jeremy Corbyn was filmed muttering something—which was interpreted by a Twitter user as "*stupid woman*"—to himself in response to a speech to Theresa May, the beleaguered British Prime Minister.

Later, in response to this Twitter accusation, Corbyn said that he had said *stupid people*, not *stupid woman*. A lot of media outlets said that several lip-readers that had viewed the footage thought that he had said *stupid woman*.

However, the other lipreaders that advised the Speaker of the House, who had to rule on whether Jeremy Corbyn had transgressed, said that it was not possible to tell which thing he had said.

If he did or did not say *stupid people*, how do we know? What is the *LINGUISTIC* evidence?

If we cannot tell, why is it that it is *LINGUISTICALLY* ambiguous and that we cannot tell?

An answer to this question would ideally involve some description of articulatory phonetics. (See, for example, StoneyB's comments below)

An explanation of visemes and how this concept bears on the question would also be very welcome.

---

Here is a video of parts of that original exchange:

[Video of May and Corbyn](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=youtube+corbyn+stupid+woman&view=detail&mid=D971B0CAD2BDE40F03D3D971B0CAD2BDE40F03D3&FORM=VIRE)

Comment: Any feedback on the downvote? I can't improve my question without it. ... (Or is it that we don't want any scientific evidence to be discussed?)

Comment: If all the experts cannot agree, it is a tall task to think this community can provide an answer.  ps:  not my dn vote.

Comment: Again, any reason for the downvote? (Or do we not want to apply scientific knowledge about linguistics to real life?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about English.  The question MIGHT be appropriate on Skeptics SE.

Comment: @lbf What experts?

Comment: Mutters are not usually carefully articulated, at the lips or anywhere else. It has to be virtually impossible to distinguish the pair of labials p..p from the pair w..m, and how much rounding does ʊ get in rapid suppressed speech?

Comment: @HotLicks It is completely and uttely a question about English in every way!!!

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, you're sneakilly answering bits of the question in comments!

Comment: @Araucaria I'll leave a formal answer to someone who can speak with authority on articulatory phonetics: somebody like, oh, you for example! And sure, my upvote--and my concurrence in your defence of the question's Anglicity.

Comment: I downvoted because, while the question is interesting, it doesn't seem to follow the spirit of being "[a] practical, answerable question based on [an] actual problem that you face." Experts are having trouble answering the question and attest how this is unanswerable, so it doesn't seem like your question is answerable with any degree of authority. (Your recent edit may change that, though - just based on what I know - that would incur a long answer.)

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin My question asks "Why is this linguistically difficult to answer?". This site doesn't cater for *problems that you face* apart from SWR's, which are widely hated and thought to be the near death of this site. Moreover, this is not a single-word-request question, but a genuine linguistics question (which is what this site is designed for). However, there has been no disagreement between experts, only amongst normal lip-readers. This is similar to normal ear-hearers - who are notoriously rubbish when given cues of any sort in ambiguous environments.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin But thank you for giving a reason for the downvote (even though I don't agree that it is in accordance with the spirit of this site). I'll definitely try and improve my posts when I can when you give me a helpful pointer.

Comment: I admit I may be confused about the application of other rules. I drew that text from here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I think that that sense of "practical" has been skewed for a normal reader by many rehashings of the guidance on questions, but  I completely agree that's how the guidance could be constued at a stretch - even given all the other descriptions of the site. However, I'm certain that *practical* means of practical use to linguists and serious enthusiasts of English language, not of practical use to learners of English for example

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Maybe you might be misunderstand my motivation. Please read my many answers here; [Pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a76472%20pronunciation)

Comment: Definitely says "stupid woman". What's the fuss? If it had been Boris Johnson, and Corbyn had silently muttered "stupid man" 90% of Britons would have agreed.

Comment: How do I go about writing an answer? Corbyn's lips move in the direction that is associated with the sounds "w" "m" and "n" in "woman".

Comment: Wow -5. This is nuts. Here's my +1 to help balance things out. I think the "problem" lies with the term *forensic linguistics*, is it a legitimate expression? Maybe to some users, it sounds pompous and pretentious? Maybe no one knows who Jeremy Corbyn is? If it had been Donald Trump, the question would have been better received. Generally speaking, Americans and most Europeans don't follow British politics.

Comment: @Marie-Lou A - "If it had been Boris Johnson, and Corbyn had silently muttered "stupid man" 90% of Britons would have agreed." Only 90%?

Comment: I think the italicised disclaimer is very irritating, and suggests some kind of pre-emptive intent, which might attract downvotes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey and Mari-Lou A The amended title was instigated after the Q got several downvotes in less than an hour. Seems to have stemmed the tide ...

Comment: (a) If you need a tag, please create it; don't include tags in the question title. (b) Is lipreading really "forensic linguistics"? Forensic, yes; linguistics — really?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I haven't used a tag in the title, have I? Articulatory phonetics is part of linguistics. So, for example, we expect labialisation - rounding and protrusion of the lips - for a realisation of /w/, but we wouldn't expect any for a /p/ before a non-rounded vowel, especially before a vowel which is accompanied lip spreading, such as /i:/.  The fact that it is not always possible to distinguish a /w/ from a /p/ is because they are both bilabials. The general difficulty of visually distinguishing an articulation of *people* from ...

Comment: Yes: "Forensic linguistics" is meta-information which should be in a tag (possibly two), not the title. If you need to explain the question in a comment, that information should be in the question. You know how this works!

Comment: @AndrewLeach ... an articulation of water is down to them both consisting of a sequence of bilabilal consonant, high vowel without lip-rounding, bilabial consonant, neutral unrounded vowel, alveolar consonant. Notice that without considerable knowledge of articulatory phonetics, it would be very difficult to come up with a word to match this, sequence off the top of ones head. And it would be foolhardy to do try and use *people* as a substitute for *women* because it is highly likely that an articulation of *woman* *WOULD* be distinguishable from *people*; the relationship is not symmetric. We

Comment: @AndrewLeach ... would be very likely to see liprounding an incomplete closure of the lips during the initial consonant, and a masking of the word final syllabic alveolar articulation by the previous bilabial one. All of this is absent from the articulation in question.

Comment: Please put all of this explanation into the question. FWIW, I have to lipread occasionally and it's perfectly obvious to me what he said.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's a precis of the more involved answer that I'm hoping someone will give.

Comment: @Mari-LouA are the directions for m and n different fom p and l though? (Do m or l have a lip direction at all - as opposed to a jaw and tongue direction?) Thanks for the upvote ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, that should say "**n** or l", of course.

Comment: I wish I had a better grasp of the jargon to explain it but I'm not able to answer this question. In my dialect the letter "n" is pronounced differently from the letter "m", my lips meet together when I pronounced "m". The letter "p" is (I think it's the right terminology) plosive

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, your right both times there, including your terminology. However, the contrast is between /m/ versus /p/ and /l/ versus /n/. Plosiveness is not visible in normal speech apart from under extreme circumstances. In other words /m/ and /p/ are the same *viseme*, so are /l/ and /n/. Both /m/ and /p/ are made with  bilabial (two-lip) complete closure. Both /l/ and /n/ are made with alveolar contact of the tongue and the alveolar ridge

Answer (score -5):

Linguistically, he said 'woman'.

Politically, one is unable to tell.

It has to be judged politically and not linguistically in order to avoid him being forced to apologise and thereby humiliated; or if refusing to apologise, being suspended from the House of Commons because it is against the rules of procedure to treat another member without respect.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Here the focus is often on explaining how we know things as well as what the answer literally is. To refer back to the original question: How do you know *linguistically* he said *woman*? Feel free to edit to provide some linguistic evidence.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. Politics do not enter into it at all.